# I have two error codes in Java I am not familiar with

Tags: java, arrays

I am a beginner at Java and I am watching instructional videos as I practice.

The code in the program however doesn't work on Eclipse IDE and pops 2 errors, I am trying to figure out why.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Arrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = new int[5];

        numbers[0] = 31;
        numbers[1] = 88;
        numbers[2] = 11;
        numbers[3] = 73;
        numbers[4] = 45;

        int[] numbers2 = {99, 1, 2, 3, 4};
        Arrays.sort(numbers);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
    }
}
```

My last two lines show the following:

1. The method `sort(int[])` is undefined for the type `Arrays`
2. The method `toString()` in the type `Object` is not applicable for the arguments (`int[]`)

Am I misunderstanding something simple?

Comment: Bad things happen when one uses such a confusing identifier as `Arrays` (your own class is being searched for those methods, but you meant to use methods on `java.util.Arrays`)

Comment: 1) Your class is called `Arrays` and you have no method called `sort`. You are presumably trying to call [the library method of the same name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])). Simplest way for you to resolve this is to call your class something different.

Comment: `Arrays.sort()` and `Arrays.toString()` are methods you should recognize - because `Arrays` is already a class in Java. So - best not to name your class Arrays - maybe MyArrays or *anything* but a pre-defined class.

Comment: Since `Arrays` is the name of your own class, you can't import `java.util.Arrays`, so you must specify the fully qualified name every time you want to use `java.util.Arrays`, i.e. `java.util.Arrays.sort(numbers)` and `java.util.Arrays.toString(numbers)`. --- Or, as others have stated, rename your class and add `import java.util.Arrays;`

Comment: *Unrelated:* Why do you have those 3 `import` statements? You don't use them for anything.

Comment: I am just following the video as is, I have no experience here. I got it solved thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the name of your class because the class `Arrays` is already part of the java API and that would create confusion

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class OtherNameThanArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] numbers = new int[5];

        numbers[0] = 31;
        numbers[1] = 88;
        numbers[2] = 11;
        numbers[3] = 73;
        numbers[4] = 45;

        int[] numbers2 = {99, 1, 2, 3, 4};

        Arrays.sort(numbers);
        Arrays.sort(numbers2);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers2));
    }


}
```

And if I can allow myself here is a second approach to sort a list differently than a table :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class OtherNameThanArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> numbers1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(31,88,11,73,45));
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(99,1,2,3,4));
        Collections.sort(numbers1);
        Collections.sort(numbers2);
        System.out.println(numbers1);
        System.out.println(numbers2);

    }
}
```

Console output for both approach:

```
[11, 31, 45, 73, 88]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 99]
```